# Scan to Array of Strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, scanf

**`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`**

In C, I initialized an array of strings, like this:

```
char* strings[20];
```

then tried to `fscanf` a bunch of stuff.

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
  fscanf(file, "%s", strings[i]);
}
```

although there is more to the program, I am sure that this is the part causing a segmentation fault. A run using gdb stated that the error was in file **`vfscanf`**, so I think this is related.

Comment: you didn't allocate memory for the strings... of course it would crash when you try to write to unknown addresses.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? I tried also doing `malloc(sizeof(char)*20)` inside the `for` loop for each string, but it did not work. I also tried `char* strings[20] = {"","","",""...};` to no avail.

Comment: You tried `strings[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*20)` inside the `for` loop? Are you sure that all 20 strings read are no more than 19 characters (keeping in mind that you need 1 char for the null-terminating character)?

Answer (score 5):

After your declaration

```
char* strings[20];  // This is an array of pointer of type char *
```

You will need to allocate memory for each pointer before you can read into them from the file.

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
  strings[i] = malloc(some_size * sizeof(char)); // allocate memory for each pointer first.
  fscanf(file, "%s", strings[i]);
}
```

Comment: This `fscanf` has a problem that it does not prevent a buffer overflow if the file contained a long word; and `fscanf` only allows supplying a compile-time constant as the buffer length.  If `some_size` is not a constant expression, you will need to rewrite this code to use some other input function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @MattMcNabb. Just want to illustrate the core issue here. But definitely you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

`char* strings[20];` does not initialize an "array of string".

Instead `strings` is an array of 20 `char *` pointers.  A strings in C is array of `char` up to an including the trailing `'\0'`.  So far, the array `Strings[]` has indeterminate values and none of the elements certainly point to a string.

By assigning those 20 pointers to various strings, you will have an "array of strings".

```
// Assign 0 (or NULL) to each pointer.
char* strings[20] = { 0 };

for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
  char buffer[100];
  if (fscanf(file, "%99s", buffer) != 1) {
    break;
  }
  strings[i] = strdup(buffer);  
  // or
  size_t len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
  strings[i] = memcpy(malloc(len), buffer, len);  // error check omitted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have a sufficiently modern POSIX-compliant version of [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) (check your system manual), you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(file, "%ms", &strings[i]) != 1)
        …report error and break/return…
}
```

With the `%ms` conversion specification, `scanf()` will use `malloc()` to allocate the appropriate amount of memory for the string it reads.  Don't forget to `free()` the memory when you're done with it.

Note that Mac OS X (10.9.5 Mavericks) does not have a sufficiently modern version of `scanf()`.  Linux (as found in Ubuntu 14.04, for example), does.